# scaling data in NN gives worse results in time and error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

Please take a look at two codes bellow. There are two setups for NN system. First code (with results) show result where data is not scaled, the second one show results with data being scaled. I am worried, because dataset is small and categorical and I can not find a solution for scaling process. Now imagine features would have continuous values and label as well. The result would be even worse. Is there something I can do to improve scaling code results?

**setup for NN in python, with no scaler:**

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,0,0], [1,1,0], [0,0,1]])
y = np.array([[0,1,0]]).T

def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(x,0,x) #relu activation

def relu_d(x): #derivate of relu
    x[x<0] = 0
    return x

np.random.seed(0)
w0 = np.random.normal(size=(3,5), scale=0.1)

w1 = np.random.normal(size=(5,1), scale=0.1)
```

**result:**

```
epoch nr:0 results in mean square error: 0.572624041985418
epoch nr:100000 results in mean square error: 0.1883460901967186
epoch nr:200000 results in mean square error: 0.08173913195938957
epoch nr:300000 results in mean square error: 0.04658778224325014
epoch nr:400000 results in mean square error: 0.03058257621363338
```

**Scaled data code:**

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,0,0], [1,1,0], [0,0,1]])
y = np.array([[0,1,0]]).T

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sx = StandardScaler()
X = sx.fit_transform(X)

sy = StandardScaler()
y = sy.fit_transform(y)


def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(x,0,x)

def relu_d(x):
    x[x<0] = 0
    return x

np.random.seed(0)
w0 = np.random.normal(size=(3,5), scale=0.1)

w1 = np.random.normal(size=(5,1), scale=0.1)
```

**result is:**

```
epoch nr:0 results in mean square error: 1.0039400468232
epoch nr:100000 results in mean square error: 0.5778610517002227
epoch nr:200000 results in mean square error: 0.5773502691896257
epoch nr:300000 results in mean square error: 0.5773502691896257
epoch nr:400000 results in mean square error: 0.5773502691896257
```

Comment: Try to remove sy = StandardScaler() and y = sy.fit_transform(y). In general the scaling is applied on the features not on the targets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the scaling is applied on the features. Here you apply it also on the targets.

Try to remove:

```
sy = StandardScaler()
y = sy.fit_transform(y)
```

and use the raw `y = np.array([[0,1,0]])` and see that happen

**EDIT 1**

You can try to binarize the labels using for example LabelBinarizer link .

If you have y values like 80,140,180... you could use this to binarize the y values and then after scaling the X features you can train the NN.

**EDIT 2**

Simple example using **multi-layer perceptron regressor and without scaling:**

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0,100,200], [1,22,44], [0,40,50] ])
y = np.array([200, 60, 20])

nn= MLPRegressor()
nn.fit(X,y)

X_new = np.array([[21,10,22]])

y_pred = nn.predict(X_new)

print(y_pred)
```

Result:

```
[ 29.28949475]
```

P.S: You can normalize/scale the data and use the same approach but this time using X_scaled (and y_scaled if this is the case). See below

**EDIT 3**

**Same but using scaling**

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X = np.array([[0,100,200], [1,22,44], [0,40,50] ])
y = np.array([200, 60, 20])

nn= MLPRegressor()

sc_x = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = sc_x.fit_transform(X)

sc_y = StandardScaler()
y_scaled = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

nn.fit(X_scaled,y_scaled)

X_new = np.array([[21,10,22]])
X_new_scaled = sc_x.fit_transform(X_new)

y_pred = nn.predict(X_new)

print(y_pred)
```

Result:

```
[ 10.03179535]
```

**EDIT 4**

If you want to binarize the values, you can use the following:

Replace

```
sc_y = StandardScaler()
y_scaled = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

With

```
sc_y = LabelBinarizer()
y_scaled = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

**Important:**

If you use `LabelBinarizer` then the `y = np.array([200, 60, 20])` will become `y_scaled`

```
[[0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But please consider, I might have cont. values like:X = np.array([[20,30,50], [40,50,90], [20,22,100]])
y = np.array([[80, 180, 144]]).T In this case scaling is a must.

Comment: I have mix of categorical and regression data. The scale will be important, however I am not sure how. I am aware I can use regression in sample case, however I would like to train NN to find solution for it.

Comment: You can try to binarize the labels using for example LabelBinarizer [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) . You could use this to binarize the y values and then after scaling the X features you can train the NN. Again if you upload your data I could provide more solutions

Comment: Thank you. here is a sample X = np.array([[0,100,200], [1,22,44], [0,40,50] etc.])), where feature one is categorical. The label is np.array([200], [60], [20],etc])). There is corelation between categorical data and label, I know I can use other machine learning models for this, but I am trying to build a NN.

Comment: Okay I see. Do you want to predict the y ? So if you train the model and then use a new X = [1,2,3] , you want to get the y as a values (like 200) or label (class 1)?

Comment: as values like(200)

Comment: @Makaroniiii I will edit my answer adding a simple example with the data that you gave me. Check in 2 minutes the answer

Comment: Thanks I will check MLP regression.

Comment: @Makaroniiii one last thing. I edited again my answer adding label binarization etc. Now , it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Without any information about the architecture and the parameters it is very difficult to pitpoint the problem.

But in general you don't need to scale binary variables. Scaling is used so that all features have similar bounds. You already have them.

Comment: Binary is not a problem. But let's assume I have mix of categorical and cont. features and cont. lables. In this case, results would be not good at all.

Comment: If you have some other features - of course it is necessary to do something. Continuous features should be scaled and categorical one hot encoded.

It is just this example has too little training data. Net simply can't learn on it. The performance should be much better on bigger datasets.

Comment: Thank you. Am just building milion size dataset to see what happens:)